# Using pipe to build a file from an async await https request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

Following the docs and a day's worth of research, I'm trying to use pipe to assemble an Excel spreadsheet returned by an API call. I get partway to saving it but the file is corrupted:

```
async function getWeeklyReport(queryString) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
request({
  url: 'https://reports.myApi.com/ReportCenter/Bookings',
  qs: queryString,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(process.env.apiEmail + ':' + process.env.apiPassword, 'utf8').toString('base64')
  }
}, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) {
    reject(error);
  } else {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      resolve(body);
    } else if (response.statusCode === 409) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(getWeeklyReport(queryString));
      }, response.headers['Retry-After'] * 1000);
    } else {
      reject(response);
    }
  }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test3.xlsm'));
```

});
}

What am I doing wrong here? test3 is created but the file is corrupted. Thanks!

Comment: when are you reading the file?

Comment: You are mixing *a lot* of async topics and they aren't mixed correctly.  You are manually returning a `Promise` from an `async` function (which will automatically wrap the return in a `Promise`) but you are also returning a pipable stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's official `request-promise` that eliminates the need for boilerplate promise constructors.

It's either promise control flow or streams. The use of promises results in getting whole response at once, so there is no need for a stream. It can be written at once, too:

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const { writeFile } = require('fs').promises;

async function getWeeklyReport(queryString) {
  let result;
  const response = await request({..., resolveWithFullResponse: true });

  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    result = response.body;
  } else if (response.statusCode === 409) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, response.headers['Retry-After'] * 1000));
    result = await getWeeklyReport(queryString);
  } else {
    throw response;
  }

  await writeFile('test3.xlsm', result);
}
```